# Smooth progressbar from textview

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar

I have a class progress bar. Depending on the set value is partially fills the text with a different color. I want when I change the current value progress filling was going smoothly from one value to another for some time, rather than by a jump, as it is now. How can I achieve that?
Code of my TextProgressBar below:

```
package com.example.app.customviews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.app.R;

public class TextProgressBar extends TextView {

private final int minValue = 0;
private int maxValue = 100;
private int currentValue = 0;
private float onePercentLenght = 1;

private int[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};
private float[] pos = {0,1};

public TextProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.TextProgressBar,
            0, 0);

       try {
           maxValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.TextProgressBar_MaxProgress, 100);
           currentValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TextProgressBar_CurrentProgress, 0);
           colors[0] = a.getColor(R.styleable.TextProgressBar_ProgressColor, Color.WHITE);
           colors[1] = a.getColor(R.styleable.TextProgressBar_MainColor, Color.BLACK);
       } finally {
           a.recycle();
       }
       initShader();
}

public TextProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initShader();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    onePercentLenght = getWidth() / maxValue;
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    initShader();
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    if(progress < minValue) {
        currentValue = minValue;
    }
    else if( progress > maxValue) {
        currentValue = maxValue;
    }
    else {
        currentValue = progress;
    }
    initShader();
    invalidate();
}

public void setMaxProgress(int progress) {
    if(progress>minValue) {
        maxValue = progress;
    }
    else {
        maxValue = minValue;
    }
    invalidate();
}

public int getMaxProgress() {
    return maxValue; 
}

public int getProgress() {
    return currentValue;
}

private void initShader() {
    float x = 0, dx =  (currentValue+1) * onePercentLenght;
    if(dx < 0) {
        dx = 0;
    }
    if(dx - 1 < 0) {
        x = 0;
    }
    else {
        x = dx - 1;
    }
    Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(x, 0, dx, 0, colors, pos, TileMode.CLAMP);
    getPaint().setShader(textShader);
}

}
```

Comment: How often are you calling setProgress?

Comment: I want to load data from server, and through this progressbar show loading progress step by step. So frequency of the steps shift depends on server load and network . Ideally, I want to achieve a smooth change between steps of progress.

Comment: You could try the first solution in my answer how it works with network callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested following approach triggering progress following way:

10, 30 with 150ms delay, 40 with 250ms delay, 80 with 50ms delay, and 100 with 450ms delay. One little weird thing is that it seems the drawing happens with little bit delay, although log print is on time, not sure if this is about my device. But this could give you something to start with. Adjusting the `MAX_INTERVAL_TIME` you can get it smoother depending how often you are settings the progress. If the callback is something you get from network, then it's nearly possible to get it all smooth since you can't predict the progress.

```
private static final int MAX_INTERVAL_TIME = 500;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

public void setProgress(final int progress) {
    final int startWidth = currentValue == maxValue ? 0 : currentValue;
    final int endWidth = (int) (maxValue * ((float) progress / maxValue));

    if (progress < minValue) {
        currentValue = minValue;
    } else if (progress > maxValue) {
        currentValue = maxValue;
    } else {
        currentValue = progress;
    }

    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(MAX_INTERVAL_TIME, 10) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            float interpolatedTime = 1 - ((float) millisUntilFinished / MAX_INTERVAL_TIME);
            currentValue = startWidth
                    + ((int) ((endWidth - startWidth) * interpolatedTime));

            initShader();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (progress == maxValue) {
                currentValue = maxValue;

                initShader();
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

If you know the time you wan't to animate the progress you could simply try following with your existing code:

```
final TextProgressBar text = (TextProgressBar) getView().findViewById(
        R.id.test);
final int animTime = 1000;

new CountDownTimer(animTime, 200) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        float progress = (1 - ((float) millisUntilFinished / (float) animTime))
                * text.getMaxProgress();
        text.setProgress((int) progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        text.setProgress(text.getMaxProgress());
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I tried your first solution with maxProgress = 5 and delay 2000ms and got same result

Comment: Which values did you trigger for setProgress and what were the delays of those calls?

Comment: I tried with MaxProgress = 5, delay = 2000 milliseconds and called setProgress(1)